# FullScreen to specific element by jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show fullscreen to specific element only when click button ! I code like below but it only show footer element and hide all child element .I want to display is footer element and all its child elements !

```js
$("footer .full").on("click",function(){
  $("body").find(":not(footer)").hide();
  $("footer").css({width:"100%",height:"100vh",position:"absolute",background:"#ccc"}).show();
  $("footer h1").text("Full Screen");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<header>
<ul>
<li>h1</li>
<li>h1</li>
<li>h1</li>
</ul>
</header>
<footer style="background:#ccc">
<h1>This is small screen</h1>
<button class="full">Full</button>
</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:not(footer) *` to exclude all child element in the `footer`.

```js
$("footer .full").on("click",function(){
  $("body").find(":not(footer) *").hide();
  $("footer").css({width:"100%",height:"100vh",position:"absolute",background:"#ccc"}).show();
  $("footer h1").text("Full Screen");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<header>
<ul>
<li>h1</li>
<li>h1</li>
<li>h1</li>
</ul>
</header>
<footer style="background:#ccc">
<h1>This is small screen</h1>
<button class="full">Full</button>
</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$("body").find(":not(footer)").hide();
```

hides everything in the footer as well.

So you could just re-show everything in the footer

```
$("footer *").show();
```

or, only hide top level items excluding the footer

```
$("body>*:not(:footer)").hide();
```

(Note there's a `>` and no space between `body` and `*` to say only top level - in your case only the `header`)

```js
$("footer .full").on("click", function() {
  $("body").find(":not(footer)").hide();
  $("footer *").show()
  $("footer").css({
    width: "100%",
    height: "100vh",
    position: "absolute",
    background: "#ccc"
  }).show();
  $("footer h1").text("Full Screen");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <header>
    <ul>
      <li>h1</li>
      <li>h1</li>
      <li>h1</li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <footer style="background:#ccc">
    <h1>This is small screen</h1>
    <button class="full">Full</button>
  </footer>
</body>
```

```js
$("footer .full").on("click", function() {
  $("body>*:not(footer)").hide();
  $("footer").css({
    width: "100%",
    height: "100vh",
    position: "absolute",
    background: "#ccc"
  }).show();
  $("footer h1").text("Full Screen");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <header>
    <ul>
      <li>h1</li>
      <li>h1</li>
      <li>h1</li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <footer style="background:#ccc">
    <h1>This is small screen</h1>
    <button class="full">Full</button>
  </footer>
</body>
```